# Solr4 index grows even when deleting documents periodically

Tags: solr, faceted-search

We are using a Solr 4 engine for generating some facets using pivoting. This index is being feed with documents, the facets generated and then the documents are being deleted. Nevertheless, the index seems to keep growing and the faceting generation gets slower. Now, if we stop the solr instance and delete the index, the faceting process recovers its speed.

Any sugestion on how to keep the process efficient? Why is the index not recovering its efficiency once the documents are deleted?

BTW, we are using Solrj and the commands we are using for deleting documents are:

```
server.deleteByQuery(...);
server.commit(true, true);
server.optimize(true, true, 1);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have read a few places that removing optimize may help. worth a try i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Basically, what we did is creating a new core, swapping the old one with the new one and then unloading the old one. That seems to solve any performance issues. For information about how to create, swap and unload cores go to http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin.